# (Flash) Dynamic text on buttons?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, text, dynamic

In Adobe Flash, I added dynamic text on top of some buttons. However, the dynamic text in front of the buttons blocks my mouse and I cannot click on the button. Is there any way (Any Actionscript 3.0 code I can write, etc.?) I can get the program to allow me to click through the text and onto the button? I also cannot change the dynamic text to static because I programmed my system to change the text based on certain conditions.

Comment: Please add some code so we can help you.

Comment: [Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365089/how-to-click-through-a-display-object-in-flash-with-as3) Basically you need to turn off `mouseChildren` and `mouseEnabled` on the textfield.

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem.